# Mouse Maze Batch File

Tags: batch-file, nested-loops, subdirectory

Edit:
Specific question: How do I set a specific variable to a specific line in a text file?
So far what I have is this:

```
set line=0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmd=findstr /r /n "^^" testCode.txt | find /C ":""
for /f %%A in ('!cmd!') do set subsets=%%A
endlocal
:a
for /f "skip=%line% delims=" %%A in (testCode.txt) do set output=%%A
set /a line+=1
echo %Line%: %output%
if %line%==%subsets% goto :b
goto:a
:b
echo.
pause
```

So if I've got three lines in my text document, testCode.txt, that read as such:

```
Red
Green
Blue
```

I want them to print into my batch file like so:

```
1: Red
2: Green
3: Blue
```

so far, it's printing like this:

```
  delims=" was unexpected at this time.
1: 
2: Blue
3: Blue
```

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, from there you can read the usage information for every command. For instance, `set /?` will show you how to both prompt the user for input, and to define a variable with a data value. `for /?`, will explain how to create a for loop etc.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to use the cmd window... thanks

Comment: So, if correctly using a for loop, and set commands, are not your issue, what exactly are you asking? This is a site dedicated to assisting you with a reproducible issue, based upon your provided code. As you've not provided any code, and you apparently know how to use the cmd window, what is the specific issue you want us to assist you with? As it currently stands, without having a problem with your commands, it appears more like please help me to structure and plan the methodology for performing an entire task. That's not what this site does, so please [edit] your question to clarify things.

Comment: And this is why i try not to insert code, bc even though I follow the instructions, it doesn't print right

Comment: @EliWhite Regarding formatting code: _Either_ prepend each line with four spaces, _or_ surround the block with lines consisting of three backticks (_not apostrophes!_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me as if you actually intend to do more than just print each of your source file lines, prepended with its line number, otherwise all you'd need was:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N "^" "testCode.txt"
```

Which would output:

```
1:Red
2:Green
3:Blue
```

What follows is therefore a `rem`arked example showing the structure and methodology, I think you intend to incorporate into your actual task to print:

```
1: Red
2: Green
3: Blue
```

Then ask the end user to make a selection from that list, by entering the line number only, and define a variable, for further use within the script, containing the content from that line:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Rem Define a variable for the intended source file.
Set "SourceFile=%~dp0testCode.txt"

Rem Exit script if the source file does not exist.
If Not Exist "%SourceFile%" Exit /B

Rem Undefine any existing variables with names beginning Line[
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('Set Line[ 2^>NUL') Do Set "%%G="

Rem Define individual variables Line[n], where n is their line number,
Rem  and print the line number followed by a colon, space and line content.
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N "^"
 "testCode.txt"') Do Set "Line[%%G]=%%H" & Echo %%G: %%H

Rem Exit the script if no line existed in the source file.
If Not Defined Line[1] Exit /B
 
Rem Assumption that the end user will need to select an entry via menu option.
:Selection
Echo(
Set "UserSelection="
Set /P "UserSelection=Enter the number for your selection>"
Set "UserSelection=%UserSelection:"=%"
(Set Line[%UserSelection%]) 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L^
 "Line[%UserSelection%]=" 1>NUL || GoTo Selection

Rem Re-define the user selection variable to the line content.
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%G In ("!Line[%UserSelection%]!") Do EndLocal & Set "UserSelection=%%~G"

Rem Print the chosen line content.
Echo(
Echo You Selected %UserSelection%

Rem For demonstration purposes only, delay the script before exiting.
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1>NUL
Exit /B
```

The code has been designed to prevent the code from continuing until the end user has entered one of the defined line numbers, *(except <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)*.

You'll note that the source file location, on line `5` uses `%~dp0` to reference the path to the directory holding your running batch file. If you source file is not located there, please use its absolute path instead.

Alternatively, you should define the current directory in your batch file from the outset, and could then choose to use relative paths throughout:

Example:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Rem Define the current working directory, and exit if it does not exist.
CD /D "W:\orking\directory" 2>NUL || Exit /B

Rem Define a variable for the intended source file.
Set "SourceFile=testCode.txt"

Rem Exit script if the source file does not exist.
If Not Exist "%SourceFile%" Exit /B

…
```

Final note, I have used `%SystemRoot%\Sytem32\`, and included the `.exe` extension, for both the `FindStr` and `Timeout` utilities. This is deliberate to prevent reliance on the script having to search the `%Path%`, and `%PATHEXT%` environment variables, *(one of which at least, is often corrupted by users ill advisedly thinking that they should modify them, and doing so incorrectly)*.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can definitely work with this and alter it to what I need it to do

Comment: If I wanted to test the line content against a text string, could I use;
do set "choiceNum[%%G]=%%H" & for %%H in (%keystring%) do echo %%G: %%H

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking. My initial instinct is that you should be filtering your lines earlier in the code, _(in the `For /F`/`findstr` loop)_, if you're only wanting to print lines containing a specific string. Could you please explain better @EliWhite. _(Sidenote: I have made a change to my above code, when just reading it back, pleas use the updated version.)_

Answer (score 0):

```
:a

if %line%==0 (SET "skipcmd=") else (set :skipcmd=skip=%line%")
set "output="

for /f "skip=%skipcmd% delims=" %%A in (testCode.txt) do if not defined output set "output=%%A"
```

should work for you [untested, but that's what I would code]

`"skip=0"` is invalid as a `skip` option, hence set `skipcmd` empty if `line` has a value of 0, otherwise set `skipcmd` to the literal `skip=3` or whatever.

Setting `output` to *nothing* will mean `output` is undefined.

Hence, after skipping the appropriate number of lines, the test `is "output" defined is applied, and on the *first* occasion this is true, so the value of` %%A`is assigned to`output`.` output`is now defined, so the`set` will be skipped for each of the remaining lines of the file.

```
:a

if %line%==0 (SET "skipcmd=") else (set :skipcmd=skip=%line%")

for /f "skip=%skipcmd% delims=" %%A in (testCode.txt) do set "output=%%A"&goto outputset
:outputset
```

would also probably work, exiting the `for` loop when the first selected line is encountered, but won't work in a `code block` (parenthesised series of lines) as a label is not allowed in a `code-block`

Tips : Use `set "var1=data"` for setting values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. In comparisons, use `if "thing1" == "thing2" ...` to avoid problems caused by spaces in `thing1/2`.